# Javascript not working with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below i have listed my links for the head and my links at the bottom of the page. The modal is not loading and i am not sure why, i believe this is an issue with my linking of the files.

Head links:

```
   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
   <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Footer:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Links below footer:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"   rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: your html is perfect, pls check ur console.log error?

Comment: Try using this jQuery include <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also make sure your bootstrap.JS is in the correct folder

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/dwqfq/) with almost your exact HTML, the only differences are that I'm linking to CDN versions of jQuery, Bootstrap 3 CSS and Bootstrap 3 JS

- As others have suggested, double check all the CSS and JS files are actually loading and there isn't a path issue
- Check all your Bootstrap CSS and JS files are consistent and for Bootstrap 3
- Comment out the carousel.css file, to verify there isn't a conflict there

HTML

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;    </button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  ...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For posterity's sake, could you edit this answer to include the specifically relevant code here? Not necessarily the entire working sample, and you can keep linking to the fiddle, of course.

Comment: Superb! Have an uppie!